# JBoss plugin missing in IntelliJ 2019.2.2

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.2 version. I want to configure Jboss 5.1 for a Java 1.6 project. I cant see JBoss in Add Configuration. See below

[image]

> I don't see a JBoss plugin in IntelliJ as well. Below are the
>   Installed Plugins

[image]

> Below are the available plugins in the market place.

[image]

Is there a way to configure IntelliJ 2019.2.2 to use JBoss 5.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable WildFly bundled plugin.
As [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WildFly), Jboss is former name:

> WildFly,formerly known as JBoss AS, or simply JBoss

Answer (score 2):

> Searched for Wildfly in IntelliJ plugins as suggested by @Konstantin Annikov
>   and enabled it. Now I have JBoss in Add/Edit Configuration.

[image]